# aws: .net Core: zip the built code and copy to s3 output bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am a **.net developer** and using a **.net core 2.x** application to **build** and **upload the release code to s3 bucket**. later that code will be used to deploy to **ec2** instance.

I am new to **CI/CD using aws** and in learning phase.

In order to create CI/CD for my sample project, I gone through some aws tutorials and was able to create the following **buildspec.yml** file. Using that file I am able to run the successful build.

The problem comes in the phase **UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS**. I am unable to understand how to create a zip file that will be used to upload to the **s3** bucket specified in the **build project**.

My **buildspec.yml** files contains the following code, Please help me finding what is wrong or what I am missing.

```
   version: 0.2

phases:
    build:
        commands:
            - dotnet restore
            - dotnet build
artifacts:
    files:
        - target/cicdrepo.zip
        - .\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\*
```

I think I have to add **post_build** and some commands that will generate the zip file. But don't know the commands.

Following is the output image from the build logs.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your file is good all what you need to do is to create a S3 bucket then
you need to configure your CodeBuild to generate zip (or not) your artifacts for you, and to store it to s3.

this is the step you need to configure:

[image]

Edit:

if you want all your files to be copied on the root of your Zip file you can use:

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - ...
  discard-paths: yes
```

Comment: I had already created the bucket and configured to use it in build configuration as you mentioned.

I had done a mistake while choosing the OS and i choose Ubuntu instead of Windows.

Comment: Now it is building the zip file in the structure bin\debug\netcoreapp2.1\
But i want all files to be copied on root.